# How to access $scope object in factory using AngularJS?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have serialize method for post , So `riskAssessmentKey` is not part of `$scope.topRiskDTO` but i pass the riskAssessmentKey value from `$scope.riskAssessmentDTO.riskAssessmentkey` and now i am posting to factory but when i  save all values are posting but riskAssessmentKey is coming undefined i dont know why..

So far tried code....

parentCtrl.js

```
$scope.addTopRisk = function(){
              topRiskGridConfig.topRiskmodalWinConfig.title = 'Add top Risk';
              $scope.viewTopRiskWin.setOptions(topRiskGridConfig.topRiskmodalWinConfig);
              $scope.$broadcast('addTopRisk',$scope.riskAssessmentDTO.riskAssessmentKey);
            };
```

childCtrl.js

```
$scope.topRiskDTO = {};
  $scope.issuePltDataSource = kendoCustomDataSource.getDropDownDataSource('RA_KY_CNCRN_IS_PLTFM');
  $scope.$on('addTopRisk', function (s,id){
    $scope.riskAssessmentDTO.riskAssessmentKey = id;
    $scope.viewTopRiskWin.open().center();
    $scope.submit = function(){
      rcsaAssessmentFactory.saveTopRisk($scope.topRiskDTO,id).then(function(){
        $scope.viewTopRiskWin.close();
      });
    };
  });
```

factory.js

```
   var serializeTopRisk = function (topRisk,id) {
          var riskAssessmentKey = id;
          var objToReturn = {
              topRiskName: topRisk.topRiskName,
              mitigationActivityDes: topRisk.mitigationActivityDes,
              issuePltfLookUpCode: topRisk.issuePltfLookUpCode,
              issueNo: topRisk.issueNo,
              riskAssessmentKey: topRisk.riskAssessmentKey
          };

          if(topRisk.riskAssessmentKey){
            objToReturn.riskAssessmentKey = topRisk.riskAssessmentKey;
          }
          return objToReturn;
      };
         saveTopRisk: function(topRisk,id) {
                      var request = serializeTopRisk(topRisk);
                      console.log('request payload', JSON.stringify(request));
                      console.log('ID :: ', id);
                      var endpoint = 'app/assessment/rest/addTopRisks';
                      return $http.post(endpoint, request);


 }
```

Comment: When and where in your code does which error occur? I have no idea what you want to say.

Comment: when i execute saveTopRisk method riskAssessmentKey is going undefined

Comment: Could you please try to remove all unnecessary code and create a plunker?

Comment: Do you mean `topRisk.riskAssessmentKey` or  `id`?

Comment: topRisk,riskAssessmentKey i want to send as id

Answer (score 2):

You forgot to pass the id to the serializeTopRisk function.

So you already pass the params correctly this this:

```
saveTopRisk: function(topRisk,id) {
                  var request = serializeTopRisk(topRisk);
```

But then serializeTopRisk should also get the id

```
var serializeTopRisk = function (topRisk, id) { // added the id over what you originally had
          var riskAssessmentKey = $rootScope.riskAssessmentDTO.riskAssessmentKey; // drop this, use id instead
```

Don't use rootScope to pass data between the factory and the controller if you don't need to (it looks like you are already passing values to the factory from the controller by supplying it with object inputs, keep it that way and drop the rootScope usage from the factory).

Comment: Thanks for helping me i edited my code in question what i have implemented as per your answer but in serialze method param(id) is undefined . Any idea why ?

Comment: when u call    rcsaAssessmentFactory.saveTopRisk($scope.topRiskDTO,id), you pass it the topRiskDTO object and the id. Is that id defined? did you pass it on to the saveTopRisk (it should take topRisk and id).

Comment: As you can see i pass it to saveTopRisk factory method params(topRiskDTo,id) so in factory method if i debug its showing id value  on $http call, but serialize method id is coming undefined i am not getting it.

Comment: u also need to pass it to serializeTopRisk if you haven't already. in the code posted above it's not passed (you only pass one param)